# Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps (State management)

Tags: flutter, state-management, flutter-lints

I've just upgraded to the major version of flutter lints and I faced this warning about using BuildContext in async methods. I found some answers for this issue without state management, but I don't understand how to use "mounted" in my provider or how to just make it the right way
[The warning in async method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxL17.png)

Comment: Show the code where the warning is.

Comment: @Alraj attached.
I'm just wondering how to make it the right way when it's used in bloc/provider or something else

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.